# JasperSoft Template Type change from xml to html

Tags: jasper-reports

Jasper files are store in XML format with extension .jrxml . Is there any way to save jasper template in HTML format and have extension .html ?

Comment: What is a reason do store report's template as *html*? The both official editors (*iReport* and *Jaspersoft Studio*) are using *jrxml* (*xml*) format - you can't even view template wtih *html* extension at *Studio*.

Comment: You can write some shell script to change file extension

Answer (score 0):

No. The .jrxml template type is the only type supported by JasperReports.

You can however export the output from the report to HTML.

E.g., given a test.jrxml, compiled to test.jasper, you can fill and export to HTML using:

```
Map<String, object> parameters = getReportParameters();
Connection connection = getDatabaseConnection();
JasperPrint print =  JasperFillManager.fillReport("test.jasper", parameters, connection);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(print, "test.html");
```

where:

- getParameters() returns any parameters you want to pass to the report
- getDatabaseConnection() returns your JDBC connection

Comment: yes, Is there workaround for the template to be of the format of HTML instead of  jrxml

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You might use [XSLT](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp) But why would you do that?

Comment: I want to have templates in HTML and output in pdf since xml is creating issue with project

Comment: You should add that information to your question, and expand on why XML is an issue.
To output to PDF is simple. Just replace the JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(print, "test.html") with JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, "test.pdf")